# Weekly data plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a big data frame (from 2007 to 2015), with data points at about every 2 minutes. I want to plot the graph of every week (from 2007 to 2015), with each week being automatically exported as a PNG file to my computer's folder. Previously, I was able to successfully produce working codes for annually, monthly, and daily plot. E.g.for yearly data:

```
for(j in 2007:2015){
mypath <- file.path("~", "Documents","Yearly", paste("WAO_AIR_Data_", j, ".png", sep = "" ))
png(filename = mypath, width = 963, height = 690) 
timePlot(selectByDate(new_subdata, year = j), 
       pollutant = c("CO2", "O2", "APO"), 
       date.pad = TRUE,
       pch = c(19,19,19),
       cex = 0.2,
       xlab = paste("Month of year in", j),
       ylab = "CO2, O2, and APO concentrations",
       name.pol = c("CO2 (ppm)", "O2 (per meg)", "APO (per meg)"),
)
dev.off()
}
```

The data frame looks like this

```
tail(new_subdata)
                   date     CO2      O2     APO
1052042 2015-12-31 23:48:45 409.636 -666.39 -353.27
1052043 2015-12-31 23:50:46 409.652 -669.62 -356.41
1052044 2015-12-31 23:52:44 409.679 -669.44 -356.09
1052045 2015-12-31 23:54:46 409.703 -667.07 -353.59
1052046 2015-12-31 23:56:44 409.719 -671.02 -357.46
1052047 2015-12-31 23:58:46 409.734      NA      NA
```

But I dont know how to produce the code for weekly plotting. Can anyone help me please? Thank you so much!

Comment: You must have a date variable. `format(Sys.Date(), '%U %Y')` will give you the current week and year, subset by that.

Comment: There is a date variable column in my data frame. And I dont just want to get the current week, I want to plot every week from 2007 to 2015, with each of them being automatically exported to my computer

Comment: @rawr, can you tell me how to do that please? Thank you

Comment: create subset variable `new_subdata$yr_wk <- format(as.Date(date), '%Y %U')` then fill in your loop `for (ii in unique(new_subdata$yr_wk)) plot(subset(new_subdata, yr_wk == ii))`

Comment: @rawr thank you very much, that worked really well for me. The only thing left for me now is to adjust the code to make better axes, but other than that it's perfect. Can you put that as an answer so I can upvote it please? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via `?strptime`, you can get the week out of a `Date` or `POSIXct` with `%U`

> `%U`
>   Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Sunday as the first day 1 of the week (and typically with the first Sunday of the year as day 1 of week 1). The US convention.

```
x <- Sys.time()
class(x); format(x, '%U')
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
# [1] "26"

x <- Sys.Date()
class(x); format(x, '%U')
# [1] "Date"
# [1] "26"
```

Using your example data with minor changes:

```
new_subdata <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "date     CO2      O2     APO
1052042 '2015-10-31 23:48:45' 409.636 -666.39 -353.27
1052043 '2015-10-31 23:50:46' 409.652 -669.62 -356.41
1052044 '2015-11-30 23:52:44' 409.679 -669.44 -356.09
1052045 '2015-11-30 23:54:46' 409.703 -667.07 -353.59
1052046 '2015-12-31 23:56:44' 409.719 -671.02 -357.46
1052047 '2015-12-31 23:58:46' 409.734      NA      NA")

## create a new grouping variable with year/week
new_subdata <- within(new_subdata, {
  yr_wk <- format(as.Date(date), '%Y %U')
})

## iterate over the unique values
jj <- unique(new_subdata$yr_wk)
# [1] "2015 43" "2015 48" "2015 52"

## do some plotting
par(mfrow = n2mfrow(length(jj)), las = 1, mar = c(5,6,2,2),
    tcl = .2, mgp = c(3,.25,0))
xr <- range(new_subdata$O2, na.rm = TRUE)
yr <- range(new_subdata$CO2, na.rm = TRUE)

for (j in jj) {
  mypath <- file.path("~", "Documents","Yearly", sprintf("WAO_AIR_Data_%s.png", j))
  # png(filename = mypath, width = 963, height = 690)
  plot(CO2 ~ O2, data = subset(new_subdata, yr_wk == j), xlim = xr, ylim = yr)
  # dev.off()
}
```

[image: myplot]

Comment: I really like the final part of the code that you made. It makes my code much shorter. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: i tried to reproduce your code for hourly data using timePlot function in openair package. The code returns an error when it reaches an hour with only 1 data point. Can you help me with that please? Thanks you!

Comment: @TungLinh the above runs without error for an example with one data point. what is the error?

Comment: your code is fine, however for my task I need to use the timePlot function in the openair package, not the usual plot function. And the timePlot function can only plot a time series, so on an hour with only 1 data point, it does not run, and returns the error:
" Error in if (days == 31) interval <- "month" : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

After a while, my solution would be to create an additional data frame with extra data of every minute, and merge it with the original data fram so the function treats them as 0 points and plot them. But doing that makes my data frame too big

Comment: So I was wondering if there is another way around that. My original data frame contains 1 million obs., and with the extra ones it'll have 5.25 million obs, which is very big for the data frame

Comment: @TungLinh that error happens when you try `if (NA == 31) do_something`, so I'm still not sure it is a single observation thing. you could also try `tryCatch(timePlot(...), error = function(e) plot.new())` which should catch the error so that your code moves on without stopping. The image for errors would be a blank plot. So you would basically wrap your plotting code (or whatever is throwing the error) in `try({code here})` or `tryCatch({code here})`

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot!